# Why does the performance of this HTML5 app drop upon coordinate load

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html5-canvas

I wrote this [Mandelbrot plotter](http://stupid-genius.com/brotplot/) in HTML5 and it has a reproducible performance bug that I can't figure out.

In the Plot Controls section, there's the ability to save coordinates into a pick list to be able to return directly there later.  If I select a saved set of coordinates, however, and then click "Load", the performance suddenly becomes so slow that at first I thought it was hanging the script (it will eventually start to develop the image as it's supposed to).

I cannot figure out why.  The onclick handler for the Load button (line #258) simply calls gotoCoord() (line #457).  The gotoCoord function simply sets several of the plot parameters (xOff, yOff, fMag) and then calls initDisplay().  I do those exact things in several other places with no ill effects (mousedown on line 124, zoomOut on line 386, zoomIn on line 394).  I can't figure out what's different about gotoCoord.

I've done repeated comparison testing, navigating to a plot and timing how long it takes to develop the image.  Then I save the coords and load them.  The performance hit is drastic.

Does anyone else see what I'm missing?

Comment: A `setInterval` of 1 millisecond is just wrong. Consider using `requestAnimationFrame` instead. And see if performance improves if you convert the loaded values to proper numbers (e.g. `xOff = +xOff`) before `initDisplay`.

Comment: That was it!!  After loading from localStorage it's text! (duh)  Thanks!

As to the interval, the frame takes about 10-15 milliseconds to process.  But after watching a stack trace, I noticed that the frames don't queue up; only one is ever processing at a time.  So, I figured why not let the next one start as soon as it can?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Allen you're mixing setInterval with setTimeout. setInterval don't care, it will try to run every 1 ms. setTimeout, when invoked, will wait the extra 1 ms. As DCoder suggested, requestAnimationFrame is a better solution. That it uses 10-15ms on *your* computer doesn't mean it will use that on someone else's computer :) requestAnimationFrame syncs to the monitor's VBLANK and will therefor work better on *all* computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered, so just taking it out of the unanswered list.

@DCoder's comment solved it.  The plot parameters are stored in localStorage and the pick list is loaded from there.  Of course, when loading from localStorage, the values will all be strings.  That's what was different about gotoCoord from the other functions.  Since the parameters are used in the plot (lines 589 and 590), the text must be converted to a number for each calculation of each pixel in each frame!

Three little plus signs fixed it.